# Keep viewport size static while adjusting Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to keep the size of the viewport static while I adjust the Chrome DevTools window?

For example, I open up DevTools and it's minimized towards the bottom of my window...

[image]

So I go to expand it. But when I do, it changes the viewport size, which in this case makes it difficult to interact with my fiddle.

[image]

In other words, I want the page rendered as if it was taking up the viewport, and when I open DevTools, it just covers up the bottom half of the viewport, without changing `innerWidth` or `innerHeight`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any option in DevTools to achieve that behaviour exactly, but you can improve the situation by enabling Responsive mode while the inspector is open:

[image: Responsive Mode]

As per above, you can expand DevTools to fill a reasonable portion of the screen, and then set the height and width of the viewport accordingly, so that you can see the content you wish to inspect.